# How to get json of model pydantic in validator function

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

Imagine I have Model of pydantic like this:

> ```
> class Input(BaseModel):
>     field1: ObjectIdField = ...
>     field2: str = ...
>     field3: int = ...
>     field4: str = ...
>
>     @validator('field4')
>     def validate_field4(cls, v, values, **kwargs):
>         # print(values) => {'field1': ObjectId('63185d5c721c6ef40eb2462a'), 'field2': 'deleted', 'field3': 1}
>         # I want to check this
>         # if json.dumps(values) == v :
>             # OK
>         # else :
>             # raise Exception
>
>     return v
>
>
>    class Config:
>       json_encoders = {
>           ObjectId: lambda v: str(v),
>        }
> ```

As you see, I want to get json of model except one field(field4).
Is there a good solution for handle this inside validator of model???

Comment: You need to use root validator, not field validator in this case: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#root-validators

Comment: my problem is how to use json encoder here ! 
I can't use json.dumps beacuse of custom field like ObjecId (Not supported)

Comment: Well, you could export your model like `Input.json()` -> https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modeljson and you can always pass `exclude` for the fields you don't need in your json

Comment: @mutantkeyboard Tnx , but I wanna use it in validator , how can I use it inside the validator ?

Answer (score 2):

What the comments failed to address is that Pydantics [`.json`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modeljson) is an **instance** method (just like the `.dict` method) and thus completely useless inside a validator, which is always a **class** method called before an instance is even initialized.

(Note: You did not provide code or explanation about how your `ObjectIdField` class works, so I had to make a guess and implement a very simple class to try and simulate the behavior you showed.)

Here is a way to accomplish your validation:

```py
import json
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class ObjectIdField:
    def __init__(self, value: str) -> None:
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"ObjectId('{self.value}')"

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.value


def encode_obj_id(obj_id: ObjectIdField) -> str:
    return str(obj_id)


def json_encode(obj: Any) -> str:
    return json.dumps(obj, default=encode_obj_id)


class Input(BaseModel):
    field1: ObjectIdField = ...
    field2: str = ...
    field3: int = ...
    field4: str = ...

    @validator('field4')
    def validate_field4(cls, v: str, values: dict[str, Any]) -> str:
        serialized = json_encode(values)
        assert v == serialized
        return v

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True  # to allow `ObjectIdField`
        json_encoders = {
            ObjectIdField: encode_obj_id,
        }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = dict(
        field1=ObjectIdField("abc"),
        field2="foo",
        field3=123,
    )
    data_json = json_encode(data)
    instance = Input(**data, field4=data_json)
    assert data_json == instance.json(exclude={"field4"})

    # instance = Input(**data, field4="invalid")  # this fails validation
```

The [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) function has a `default` parameter, which takes a function

> that gets called for objects that can’t otherwise be serialized.

We can use that to construct our own little helper function **`json_encode`** that serializes `ObjectIdField` types using the `encode_obj_id` function.

Since `field4` is not present in the `values` dictionary passed to the validator function for that field, we can simply call our `json_encode` function on that dictionary and compare it to the `field4` value `v`.

**NOTE**: This only works, if `field4` is defined **last** on the model because fields are validated in the order they are defined. If you had another field *after* `field4` on your model, its value would be missing from the `values` dictionary by the time the validator was called.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This code helped me , Tnx: 
 json.dumps(obj, default=encode_obj_id)